# knockout binding - working with 'id' but not with 'name'

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to learn knockoutjs by studying existing sourcecodes and making small changes to them..
The source code that I'm trying to understand here is an example of knockout-sortable.js by RP Niemeyer.

The original example code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UdXr4/)

I have made some small changes which are [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/744/)

The changes in this code as shown below is addition of a property "name" in table:

```
var Table = function(id, name, students) {
    this.students = ko.observableArray(students);
    this.students.id = id;
    this.students.name=name;
};
```

And consecutive changes in the data:

```
var initialTables = [
    new Table(1,"Table One",  [
        new Student(1, "Bobby", "male"),
        new Student(2, "Ted", "male"),
        new Student(3, "Jim", "male")
    ]),
    new Table(2,"Table Two", [
        new Student(4, "Michelle", "female"),
        new Student(5, "Erin", "female"),
        new Student(6, "Chase", "male")
    ]),
    new Table(3,"Table Three", [
        new Student(7, "Denise", "female"),
        new Student(8, "Chip", "male"),
        new Student(9, "Kylie", "female")
    ]),
    new Table(4,"Table Four", [
        new Student(10, "Cheryl", "female"),
        new Student(11, "Doug", "male"),
        new Student(12, "Connor", "male")
    ]),
    new Table(5,"Table Five", [
        new Student(13, "Cody", "male"),
        new Student(14, "Farrah", "female"),
        new Student(15, "Lyla", "female")
    ])
];
```

As table id has changed from a string "Table Five" to a number -5, consecutive changes can be viewed in result pane..

Now, I change the html code from `<span data-bind="text: students.id"></span>` to `<span data-bind="text: students.name"></span>` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/746/)

Now I had hoped that the changes in table name will go back to "Table Five" but it is showing just a single alphabet 'd'

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong..

Also I have added `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(tables,null,2)"></pre>` to view tables observable.
It is showing the following data:

```
[
  {
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bobby",
        "gender": "male"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ted",
        "gender": "male"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jim",
        "gender": "male"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "students": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Michelle",
        "gender": "female"
      },
-----and so on-------
```

As can be seen its showing only the students array.. What do I need to do to add tables property- 'id' and 'name' to this..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout observable arrays have a `.name` (because they are really just a function with knockout extras) property that you shouldn't try to use or overwrite. Try naming that property something else, or, even better, don't attach it to the observableArray, and attach it to the table itself:

```
var Table = function(id, name, students) {
    this.students = ko.observableArray(students);
    this.students.id = id;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fzr4qfa8/

Answer (score 2):

`students` in this case is an `observableArray`, which is a function. In many browsers, the `name` property of a function is read-only. If you want to add a property like that directly to your observableArray, then you would want to pick a different name (as @xdumaine noticed in the comment above).